# In a rails 4 app I am having trouble passing the csrf token with an answer in jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, csrf-protection

Page html:

```
<head>
  ...
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  ...
</head>
```

jquery:

```
$(".on_click").click(function() {
    $("#spinner").show();

    var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
    var ans = $(this).attr('ans');
    var url = ... + "/?ans=" + ans + "&_csrf=" + token;

    $.post(url, function(html) {
        $("#spinner").hide();
    });
});
```

UPDATE:

oops... forgot to mention the error: `Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What issues are you having? Do you get an error? I'd guess it needs to be sent in the POST payload, not the URL.

Comment: I'd recommend using Ajax instead of $.post, so you can set a request header before sending the answer.

Comment: @Hipady `$.post` makes an AJAX call. Do you mean `$.ajax`?

Comment: Yes that's what I was referring to :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the token to send in all request in such way:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
});
```

Or for a specific request such as yours:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: 'YOUR URL HERE',
    type: 'POST',
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))},
      data: //data here,
      success: function(response) {
        //some code
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: @ceejayoz and Hp, I was just making a plain, old $.post... without using $.ajax. Is there not a way to send the token while using $.post? If not, then of course I'll use conventional $.ajax and set the type. Is there more security in using $.ajax instead of $.post?

Comment: @Jay if you want to be able to handle errors, do something before sending or when the call is complete regardless of success or fail, $.post() only supports a success callback, where $.ajax() supports beforeSend, success, error and complete callbacks. I generally prefer to always use $.ajax()